# Apex - Looping Subquery of Records

Tags: apex, map

In my apex class that handles triggers I query the account along with the related lists of an object.
If I use this in execute anonymous I can see the account team records.

```
List<Account> acct = [SELECT Id, Name,
                     (SELECT Name, Underwriter __c FROM Account_Teams__r)
                      FROM Account];
                      
for(Account a : acct){
    for(Account_Team__c at : a.account_Teams__r){
        //system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'here is the at ' + at);
    }
}
```

But if I try to do the same using a map in my trigger method, the account team records are not returned.
Does this have something to do with using a map?  The first debug shows the account, however, the second debug does not show any related account team records.
thanks!

```
map<Id, Account> accountmap = new Map <Id, Account>(clsUtility.GetAccountInfo(accountIds));

for(Account a : accountmap.values()){
    system.debug(logginglevel.info,'here is the accountmap values '+ a);
    for(Account_Team__c at : a.account_Teams__r){
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'here is the at ' + at);
    }
}
```

```
//get account information
public static Map<Id, Account> GetAccountInfo (List<Id> PassedA){
    Map<Id, Account> aInfo = new Map<Id, Account>();
    List<Account> acct = [select Id, Name, RecordTypeID, Potential_Total_Employees__c, 
                    Potential_NJ_Employees_Residents__c, Health_Market__c, Health_Group_Number__c, 
                    Health_Underwriter_Assigned__c, Dental_Market__c, Dental_Group_Number__c,
                    Dental_Status_Auto__c, Health_Status_Auto__c, RX_Status_Auto__c, customer_any_lob__c,Health_Last_Known_Carrier__c,
                    RX_Last_Known_Carrier__c, Dental_Last_Known_Carrier__c, Expat_Current_Carrier__c, SL_Last_Known_Carrier__c,
                    Expat_Total_Employees__c, vision_last_known_carrier__c, vision_status_auto__c, Vision_Comments__c,
                    Agency_Broker__c, Agency_status__c, (select Name, Health_Underwriter_Assigned__c from Account_Teams__r) from Account
                       where Id IN : PassedA];
    for(Account a : acct){
        aInfo.put(a.id, a);
    }

    return aInfo;
}
```

Comment: Can you show whats in this `clsUtility.GetAccountInfo(accountIds)`. And confirm whats going in `accountIds` and if those accounts really have account team member. Also confirm what is sharing setting for account and `clsUtility` is declared with `with sharing` or `without sharing`

Comment: Thank you!  AccountIds are being set looking the trigger context from opportunity.  I confirmed that they are getting populated correctly.  I added the clsUtility method (not sure why it looks the way it does when posting it)  AS far as the sharing of the clsUtiltiy, its not defined but the object is public read access.  thanks!

Comment: PS you can use `new Map<Id, Account>([select...]);` instead of looping over every record.